# the login system in Laravel showing me These credentials do not match our records

Tags: laravel, authentication, model

hi guys  i got this issue

the login system in laravel showing me

> These credentials do not match our records.

in Admin model i have

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'phone','email','password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


}
```

in AdminController i have

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Admin;
use App\Auth;
class adminController extends Controller


{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('Auth:admin');
    }




    public function index(){
        return view('admin/home');
    }
}
```

in the migration databse i have this

```
     <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
    class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('phone')->nullable();
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->string('password');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
        }
    }
```

i did insert admin username and password manually but when i try to login i get.

the login system in laravel showing me

> These credentials do not match our records.

i even dropped the database and recreated new one but ..the same problem

Comment: Never done this myself, but I dont think that just because you make an Admin model that extends authenticatable, that it will work with the default login form.

Comment: Also, you should reconsider making a separate table for admins without a good reason and instead consider something like https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission, and create an Admin role instead.

Comment: Please read: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Comment: yes i have default login user and it working there but i did like multi auth  so with admin not working...  says.  These credentials do not match our records

Comment: How did you "i did like multi auth"?

Comment: i mean one longin system with 2 sides .. login for admin and login for users ... with users its working and login in and login out and register like like the defualt but with admin  it shows These credentials do not match our records ,, i dont know where is wrong

Comment: Yes that's what I am trying to point out. you did not do multi auth. You just made a new model that extends authenticatable. I don't think Laravel's default login controller has any idea it should look at your admins table and users table for credentials. you should look at an external package like: https://github.com/bitfumes/laravel-multiauth to achieve this.